# Why doesn't Google provide a floating action button widget?

Tags: android, material-design

I've been really trying to soak up everything about Android development, including material design stuff.

My question though is about the floating action button in particular. If it's an integral part of the material design guidelines, how do they expect rookie developers (like myself) to use it easily? I've found lots of github projects with floating action buttons, but I'd really love an official one.

I've done a decent amount of development, and even done [an Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.app.studios.on.game) with some of my classmates. We put a floating action button in our app, but we just used one we found on github. In the real world, do people just find one they like and add it to all their apps as a gradle dependency?

Sorry for being ignorant, I have little experience in the professional world. But it just seems to me that if Google wants developers to adopt this, they would make it really really easy to add it to an app.

Thanks!
-Justin

Comment: Coz maybe its very easy to create. If you think you want a feature , you put it as a feature request in the android codebase.

Comment: @Radix , well no - this said, you would be forced to implement a normal button, too

Comment: It's literally ordinary `ImageButton` with a custom oval drawable as background...

Comment: It is coming... not ready yet. Take a look here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.java

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the new version of v7 appcompat library .
http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html

Google is trying hard to Materialise the pre-Lollipop devices(added Palette, added AppCompatDialog and a bunche of compat views), so your floating button may just be around the corner :)